# How do I correctly destroy a MobFox ad?

Tags: android, advertisements

Is anyone here using MobFox to display their Android app's ads?  I was previously using the AdMob SDK but recently switched to MobFox and while it only took a short time to integrate it, there are a few outstanding issues which I can't work out.

With the AdMob SDK, in my **onDestroy** method, I would have this line:

```
adView.destroy();
```

However, I've looked through MobFox but I can't see an equivalent, am I missing something?!

(there is all the usual **pause();**, **resume** methods etc..... just can't find a **destroy()** method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found it.  For anyone else wondering about this, the correct method to call is:

```
adView.release();
```